# How to concatenate several parametrized fixtures into a new fixture in py.test?

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

If I have two parametrized fixtures, how can I create a single test function that is called first with the instances of one fixture and then with the instances of the other fixture?

I guess it would make sense to create a new fixture that somehow concatenates the two existing fixtures. This works well for "normal" fixtures, but I don't seem to get it to work with parametrized fixtures.

Here is a simplified example of what I tried:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
def lower(request):
    return "i" * request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def upper(request):
    return "I" * request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=['lower', 'upper'])
def all(request):
    return request.getfuncargvalue(request.param)

def test_all(all):
    assert 0, all
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
request = <SubRequest 'lower' for <Function 'test_all[lower]'>>

    @pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
    def lower(request):
>       return "i" * request.param
E       AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'
```

... and the same error for `upper()`.

What did I do wrong?

How can I fix this?

---

**UPDATE:**

There is a PyTest plugin that can be used to solve this problem: https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture.

After `pip`-installing this plugin, the only necessary change to the above code is the following:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[pytest.lazy_fixture('lower'),
                        pytest.lazy_fixture('upper')])
def all(request):
    return request.param
```

Note, however, that there are some complex cases in which it will not work:

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3244#issuecomment-369836702

Related PyTest issues:

- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349
- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/460
- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3244

Comment: I saw that there is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/349/using-fixtures-in-pytestmarkparametrize) on the py.test tracker which would probably solve my problem, but there wasn't yet a response from the py.test devs.

Comment: There is [another issue](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/460/attributeerror-subrequest-object-has-no) which seems related to my question, but no response either ...

Comment: The [`pytest-lazy-fixture`](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture) plugin lets you do this.

Comment: @ChristianLong Thanks for the hint! I've added some information above.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a solution available in `pytest-cases`, named `fixture_union`. Here is how you create the fixture union that you requested in your example:

```
from pytest_cases import fixture_union, pytest_fixture_plus

@pytest_fixture_plus(params=[1, 2, 3])
def lower(request):
    return "i" * request.param

@pytest_fixture_plus(params=[1, 2])
def upper(request):
    return "I" * request.param

fixture_union('all', ['lower', 'upper'])

def test_all(all):
    print(all)
```

It works as expected:

```
<...>::test_all[lower-1] 
<...>::test_all[lower-2] 
<...>::test_all[lower-3] 
<...>::test_all[upper-1] 
<...>::test_all[upper-2]
```

Note that I used `pytest_fixture_plus` in the above example because if you use `pytest.fixture` you will have to handle yourself the cases where a fixture is not actually used. This is done as follows, for example for the `upper` fixture:

```
import pytest
from pytest_cases import NOT_USED

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def upper(request):
    # this fixture does not use pytest_fixture_plus 
    # so we have to explicitly discard the 'NOT_USED' cases
    if request.param is not NOT_USED:
        return "I" * request.param
```

See [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/#fixture_union) for details. (I'm the author by the way ;) )

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52307317/2988730) (and received a similar, but distinct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52321058/2988730)). The best solution I was able to come up with was to reconsider how I parametrize my tests. Instead of having multiple fixtures with compatible outputs, I used the fixtures as regular functions, and just parametrized your meta-fixture to accept the function name and arguments:

```
import pytest

def lower(n):
    return 'i' * n

def upper(n):
    return 'I' * n

@pytest.fixture(params=[
    (lower, 1),
    (lower, 2),
    (upper, 1),
    (upper, 2),
    (upper, 3),
])
def all(request):
    func, *n = request.param
    return func(*n)

def test_all(all):
    ...
```

In your particular case, unpacking `n` into a list and passing it with `*` is slightly overkill, but it provides generality. My case has fixtures that all accept different parameter lists.

Until pytest allows us to properly chain fixtures, this is the only way I have come up with to run 5 tests instead of 12 in your situation. You can make the list shorter with something like

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    *[(lower, i) for i in range(1, 3)],
    *[(upper, i) for i in range(1, 4)],
])
```

There is an actual advantage of doing it this way. You can pick and chose which tests you want to do special things to, like XFAIL, without affecting a whole swath of other tests if you have additional dependencies in your pipeline.

Comment: Well the main point of fixtures is that they can be re-used, right? And if I create a parametrized fixture, I also want to re-use the parametrization (because it's part of the fixture). The way you suggest it, I can't re-use the parametrization. Imagine there are more fixtures like `lower` and `upper` and I want to make several different combinations of them. The [lazy_fixture](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture) plugin lets me do exactly that without having to manually repeat anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is not beautiful, but may be today you know the better way.

Request object inside 'all' fixture know only about own params: 'lower', 'upper'. One way [using fixtures from a fixture function](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#modularity-using-fixtures-from-a-fixture-function).

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
def lower(request):
    return "i" * request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def upper(request):
    return "I" * request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=['lower', 'upper'])
def all(request, lower, upper):
    if request.param == 'lower':
        return lower
    else:
        return upper

def test_all(all):
    assert 0, all
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But using both `lower` and `upper` as function arguments for `all()` runs the tests for all combinations (I guess more accurately the Cartesian product) of `lower()` and `upper()`, i.e. 6 times. Adding two `params` to `all()` doubles the number, i.e. `test_all()` runs 12 times. I would like to have only the concatenation of `lower()` and `upper()`, i.e. running the test only 5 times.